# Creating a Custom Picker View

Tags: ios, uikit, uipickerview, uicontrol

I am trying to create a reusable UIPickerView not unlike UIDatePicker for use in multiple table views. The view works great, but as it's delegate needs to be itself (in order to set the components and rows), I cannot implement the didSelectRow:inComponent: method (to update labels and the model) in the tableViewControllers it is being used in.

How can I subclass UIPickerView and still provide a delegate? If UIDatePicker can do it, I'm guessing there's a pretty straightforward way.

Comment: Don't subclass `UIPickerView`. Subclass `UIView` and have your implementation add the picker as a subview. Define your own protocols as needed.

Comment: Agreed with @rmaddy, since youre using it in a tableview create a subclass of `UITableViewCell` and the cell will be the delegate of the pickerview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspecting the UIDatePicker, it is a subclass of UIControl and follows the target-action pattern. It appears Apple just adds a UIPickerView as a subview to the UIControl. UIDatePicker has made it since the original SDK, so I think I will stick with this method for creating a custom, self-contained PickerView.

More information on custom implementing a custom UIControl: http://www.raywenderlich.com/76433/how-to-make-a-custom-control-swift